# Package name doesn't match when uploading app to google play

Tags: android, google-play

When i try to upload new version of my app to google play i get error saying that the package name of my apk is wrong and it has to be com.witanowski.sportilicious.

[image]

However package name of my project seems to be correct

[image]

I renamed package name of the project once and maybe there is some file that still has old package name and therefore im getting this error. Ill be grateful for any ideas.

**EDIT:**

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.witanowski.sportilicious">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".main.OverviewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.MeasurementListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.MapActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.SettingsListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.SummaryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.DisciplineListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.AppInfoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.UserProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.StatisticsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.HistoryListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.WeatherActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".main.DeviceListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".service.BluetoothLeService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you show us the content of your AndroidManifest.xml file (hiding keys and things you wanna keep private)

Comment: Show us the Gradle file too, there may be a definition of a different package name there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to JonZarate's comment, I found out what was wrong. In my gradle file i didn't rename applicationId properly when I was changing package name, that's why I was getting this error.